# Woocommerce: Losing currency in ajax call

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I have a Woocommerce site that uses the Woocommerce Multilingual plugin from WPML to handle currencies. I am trying to get the cart amount in an AJAX-call, but I get wrong currency for some reason. If I use the same method (get_cart_subtotal) in a page template the correct currency is used.

Here is my very simple ajax-action:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_cart_total', function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
});
```

I am using:

- WooCommerce 2.5.5
- WPML Multilingual CMS 3.3.8 WooCommerce
- Multilingual 3.7.13

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wc_ajax instead of wp_ajax. Change also code in .js - it could be something like that:

```
$.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'get_cart_total'), data, function(response) {
        if (!response) {
            return;
        } else {
            //do something
        }
});
```